# Gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1 Error

Tags: iphone, xcode, gcc, build

I am getting this error when i am trying to build my app. In the simulator it works fine but when coming to build for ipa it gives the following error:

> Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

What is causing this error?

**Edited**

> Ld
>   build/halalgauge.build/Release-iphoneos/halalgauge.build/Objects-normal/armv6/halalgauge
>   normal armv6 cd /Users/admin/Desktop/ShopSavvy setenv
>   IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.2 setenv PATH
>   "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch
>   armv6 -isysroot
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk
>   -L/Users/admin/Desktop/ShopSavvy/build/Release-iphoneos -L/Users/admin/Desktop/ShopSavvy -L/Users/admin/Desktop/ShopSavvy/Classes/ZBarSDK -L/Users/admin/Desktop/ShopSavvy/Classes/ScannerKit-4.0.3 -F/Users/admin/Desktop/ShopSavvy/build/Release-iphoneos -filelist /Users/admin/Desktop/ShopSavvy/build/halalgauge.build/Release-iphoneos/halalgauge.build/Objects-normal/armv6/halalgauge.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -map -Xlinker /Users/admin/Desktop/ShopSavvy/build/halalgauge.build/Release-iphoneos/halalgauge.build/halalgauge-LinkMap-normal-armv6.txt
>   -dead_strip all_load -lstdc++ -miphoneos-version-min=4.2 -framework CoreGraphics -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreVideo -framework
>   CoreMedia -framework Foundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework
>   QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework iAd -lsqlite3.0 -framework
>   MessageUI -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework
>   MapKit -framework CoreLocation -liconv -lScannerKit -framework
>   SystemConfiguration -framework MediaPlayer -o
>   /Users/admin/Desktop/ShopSavvy/build/halalgauge.build/Release-iphoneos/halalgauge.build/Objects-normal/armv6/halalgauge
>
> arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: all_load: No such file or directory
>   Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
>   failed with exit code 1

Comment: Could be due to any number of errors in your code.

Comment: i have only 2 errors the two errors are same

Comment: Yeah but what are the errors?

Comment: Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Comment: This is an old post, but just in case: see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293298/llvm-gcc-4-2-error/7833677#7833677)
Basically, the link from gcc-4.2 to llvm-gcc-4.2 in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ was missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect the linker invocation, you’ll see the following:

```
-dead_strip all_load -lstdc++
```

The linker interprets that `all_load` as a file that must be linked, hence the error:

> arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: all_load: No such file or directory

You need to specify `-all_load` (with an hyphen) instead of `all_load` in the linker flags.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your Mac, and if all else fails choose either LLVM-GCC or LLVM as a compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Could be due to multiple errors.

In XCode's build window select All Messages, that should give more meaningful information, which you can post here to help trace the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add required library from the SDK libraries.