# Xcode ProcessPCH iPhone Simulator compile error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, compiler-errors, ios-simulator

```
ProcessPCH /Users/Greg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Reflect-bliqehhvpcjjkbevedebyovpynnh/Build/PrecompiledHeaders/Reflect_Prefix-gjmfeslmwxdsbnejtxlenykhtzkb/Reflect_Prefix.pch.gch Reflect_Prefix.pch normal armv6 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42
cd /Users/Greg/Dropbox/Documents/Personal/Code/Reflect
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -x objective-c-header -arch armv6 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -fexceptions -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -fvisibility=hidden -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=30000 -iquote /Users/Greg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Reflect-bliqehhvpcjjkbevedebyovpynnh/Build/Intermediates/Reflect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Reflect.build/Reflect-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/Greg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Reflect-bliqehhvpcjjkbevedebyovpynnh/Build/Intermediates/Reflect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Reflect.build/Reflect-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/Greg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Reflect-bliqehhvpcjjkbevedebyovpynnh/Build/Intermediates/Reflect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Reflect.build/Reflect-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/Greg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Reflect-bliqehhvpcjjkbevedebyovpynnh/Build/Intermediates/Reflect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Reflect.build/Reflect-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/Greg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Reflect-bliqehhvpcjjkbevedebyovpynnh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/Greg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Reflect-bliqehhvpcjjkbevedebyovpynnh/Build/Intermediates/Reflect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Reflect.build/DerivedSources/armv6 -I/Users/Greg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Reflect-bliqehhvpcjjkbevedebyovpynnh/Build/Intermediates/Reflect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Reflect.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/Greg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Reflect-bliqehhvpcjjkbevedebyovpynnh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -c /Users/Greg/Dropbox/Documents/Personal/Code/Reflect/Reflect_Prefix.pch -o /Users/Greg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Reflect-bliqehhvpcjjkbevedebyovpynnh/Build/PrecompiledHeaders/Reflect_Prefix-gjmfeslmwxdsbnejtxlenykhtzkb/Reflect_Prefix.pch.gch

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 255
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I get this error when compiling for the simulator, and it's project specific (I tried another project and it worked), so there's probably something wrong with my project settings. Anyone know what exactly?

Comment: Have al look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293298/llvm-gcc-4-2-error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed the problem. I changed the architectures to `Standard(armv6 armv7)` rather than just `armv6 armv7`.